What is the persist directory path?
type here# Vector Database
persist_directory = ""  # Persist directory path
embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")


what should give in the persist directory. please help me
i don't know what should i give as I am a new programmer

Ordinarily, Chroma uses ephemeral storage (not permanent) intended for when you are just trying things out.
If you want the data to persist across client restarts, the persist_directory is the location on disk where Chroma stores the data on disk. Set persist_directory to the disk directory path where you want to store your data so it will be automatically loaded when the client starts.
For additional info, see the Chroma Usage Guide. Cheers!
